# im trying to pick a image from gallery but getting error

Tags: react-native

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
pickImage=()=>{
  captureVideo = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({

      mediaType: 'video',

    }).then((video) => {
      console.log(video);
      this.setState({ video_info: video, video: video, show: false });
    });
   
  };
 }
export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickImage}>
        <Text >Select Single With Camera</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

but im getting this error:Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-image-crop-picker\index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ImageCropPicker.openPicker')

i really need help now...

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the module you are using. Try reinstalling it. If you are using Expo, maybe that module is not compatible. Use [expo image picker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) instead.